# Application crashes Python when performing a function

Tags: python, crash, pycharm

I'm having a hard time finding out why python crashes when I run this application using PyCharm. 
I insert the url to the file (https://download.scdn.co/SpotifySetup.exe) and the save location (D:\). As soon as I press "Download", Python stops working.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import urllib.request


class Downloader(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        url = QLineEdit()
        save_location = QLineEdit()
        progress = QProgressBar()
        download = QPushButton("Download")
        progress.setValue(0)
        progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

        url.setPlaceholderText("URL")
        save_location.setPlaceholderText("Save folder:")

        layout.addWidget(url)
        layout.addWidget(save_location)
        layout.addWidget(progress)
        layout.addWidget(download)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Downloader")
        download.clicked.connect(self.download)

    def download(self):
        url = self.url.text()
        save_location = self.save_location.text()
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, save_location, self.report)

        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, save_location, self.report)
        except Exception:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Warning", "The download failed")
            return

        QMessageBox.information(self, "Information", "The Download is complete")
        self.progress.setValue(0)
        self.url.setText("")
        self.save_location.setText("")


    def report(self, blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
        readsofar = blocknum * blocksize
        if totalsize > 0:
            percent = readsofar * 100 / totalsize
            self.progress.setValue(int(percent))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dl = Downloader()
dl.show()
app.exec_()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: fix your code indentation, it's messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code to run in PyCharm by adding `self` to a few variable names.

- `url -> self.url`
- `save_location -> self.save_location`
- `progress -> self.progress`

Here is a gist of the updated code:

- https://gist.github.com/delirious-lettuce/324fdb51f1fdd0cfd76bfd257ea17e05

Comment: But whats that got to do with pycharm and the crash? I'm investigating crashing on my side, also GUI.